# My contract doesnt get published on ropsten etherscan

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, compiler

I get the following error: Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI

I've seen other people experiencing the same issue but their solutions don't work for my issue. I don't use libraries nor do I have constructor arguments and I did select the right compiler(v0.4.20+commit.3155dd80).

This is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

import './SafeMath.sol';
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract Damble is usingOraclize{
using SafeMath for uint256;

mapping(address => uint) public users;
mapping(uint => bool) private allowedValues;
address[] public userAddresses;
uint[] public partAmounts;
address owner;

uint minEther;
uint public totalEth;
uint maxUsers;
uint maxValue = 5 ether;
uint public randomNumber;
function Damble() {
    owner = msg.sender;
    minEther = 0.5 ether;

    // these are the only allowed values in this lobby, if the value is something else the user has been playing around with the code
    allowedValues[(1 ether / 100)] = true;
    allowedValues[(1 ether / 10)] = true;
    allowedValues[(1 ether / 4)] = true;
    allowedValues[(1 ether / 2)] = true;
    allowedValues[(1 ether)] = true;
    allowedValues[(5 ether)] = true;
}

event NewUser(address userAddress, uint amount);
event WinnerPicked(address winner);
event NewRandomNumber_bytes(bytes);
event NewRandomNumber_uint(uint);
event ProofFailed();


function placeBet() public payable{
    require(msg.value <= maxValue && msg.value > 0);
    require(allowedValues[msg.value]);

    if (users[msg.sender] > 0) {
        userPullout(); //Remove senders data
    }

    // Push senders data again.
    userAddresses.push(msg.sender);
    partAmounts.push(msg.value);
    totalEth = SafeMath.add(msg.value, totalEth);
    users[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    NewUser(msg.sender, msg.value);
}


function getPartAmounts() view public returns(uint[]){
    return partAmounts;
}

function getUserBalance(address user) view public returns(address, uint){
    return(user, users[user]);
}

function accountAmount() view public returns(uint) {
    uint arrLen = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < userAddresses.length; i++) {
        if (users[userAddresses[i]] > 0){
            arrLen++;
        }
    }
    return arrLen;
}

function minEthIsMet() view public returns(bool){
    return (totalEth >= minEther);
}

function userPullout() private {
    require(users[msg.sender] > 0);
    for (uint i = 0; i < userAddresses.length; i++) {
        if (userAddresses[i] == msg.sender){
            delete userAddresses[i];
            delete partAmounts[i];
        }
    }

    totalEth = SafeMath.sub(totalEth, users[msg.sender]);
    msg.sender.transfer(users[msg.sender]);
    users[msg.sender] = 0;
}


function pickWinner(uint randomNumber) view private returns(address){
    uint lastMax = 1;

    for (uint i = 0; i < userAddresses.length; i++) {
        if (randomNumber >= lastMax && randomNumber <= (users[userAddresses[i]] + lastMax)){
            WinnerPicked(userAddresses[i]);
            return (userAddresses[i]);
        }
        lastMax =  SafeMath.add(users[userAddresses[i]], lastMax);
    }
}



function endRaffle() public{
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    require(accountAmount() > 1);
    require(totalEth >= minEther);

    address winner = pickWinner(randomNumber);
    if (winner == address(0)){
        onNoAddress();
    } else {
        uint winnings; 
        if (SafeMath.div((SafeMath.mul(totalEth, 98)), 100) > this.balance) {
            winnings = SafeMath.div((SafeMath.mul(totalEth, 98)), 100);
        } else {
            winnings = SafeMath.div((SafeMath.mul(this.balance, 98)), 100);
        }

        winner.transfer(winnings);
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    totalEth = 0;
    clearParticipants();
}

function getContractBalance() public view returns(uint){
    return address(this).balance;
}

function clearParticipants() private {
    for (uint i = 0; i < userAddresses.length; i++) {
        users[userAddresses[i]] = 0;
        delete userAddresses[i];
        delete partAmounts[i];
    }
}

function onNoAddress() private{
    for (uint i = 0; i < userAddresses.length; i++) {
        userAddresses[i].transfer(users[userAddresses[i]]);
        users[userAddresses[i]] = 0;
    }
}


// Orazlized code
function __callback(bytes32 _queryId, string _result, bytes _proof)
{ 
    if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;

    if (oraclize_randomDS_proofVerify__returnCode(_queryId, _result, _proof) != 0) {
        ProofFailed();
        // the proof verification has failed, do we need to take any action here? (depends on the use case)
    } else {
        // for simplicity of use, let's also convert the random bytes to uint if we need
        uint maxRange = totalEth -1; // deduct one so that when one gets added later it cant be bigger than the total eth.
        randomNumber = (uint(sha3(_result)) % maxRange) + 1; // this is an efficient way to get the uint out in the [1, maxRange] range

        NewRandomNumber_uint(randomNumber); // this is the resulting random number (uint)
    }
}

function getRandomNumber() payable { 
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    require(accountAmount() > 1);
    require(totalEth >= minEther);

    oraclize_setProof(proofType_Ledger); // sets the Ledger authenticity proof
    uint N = 4; // number of random bytes we want the datasource to return
    uint delay = 0; // number of seconds to wait before the execution takes place
    uint callbackGas = 200000; // amount of gas we want Oraclize to set for the callback function
    bytes32 queryId = oraclize_newRandomDSQuery(delay, N, callbackGas);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan won't follow imports at all. You have

```
import './SafeMath.sol';
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";
```

But Etherscan doesn't have the same files in its workspace to import. You need to replace those imports with the contents of the files they're importing.

Beyond that, you should also check compiler arguments (in addition to compiler version). Things like how many rounds of optimization will impact the generated byte code. If you use Truffle for compilation, that's likely to be an issue after you get past the imports.

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan does not support imports. You will need to concatenate into a single .sol file.

Try using a flattener from the below:
https://github.com/BlockCatIO/solidity-flattener
https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-flattener